# how can I get selected text

Tags: c, winapi, text, copy, selection

I wonder how can I get selected text. (usually done by mouse dragging or shift + arrow on text)

From notepad, word, Internet explorer addressbar, etc.

sending WM_GETTEXT just copy caption, and unable to copy selected text while I rename file name on file explorer.

So, I am considering simulating Ctrl+C. but simulating key strokes seems not a good idea. because it will make side effects.(in case Ctrl+C assigned to other functionality)

I tried following code, wishing copy currently selected text into clipboard

```
OpenClipboard(0);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,0);
CloseClipboard();
```

but no luck, it just emptyclipboard.

how can I copy currently selected text?

(simulating Ctrl+c with no unpredictable effect)

thanks!
(my environments are Windows 7, C programming language, winapi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a general answer because the various applications you mentioned use different window classes.
For Notepad in particular: The display area seems to be a simple `EDIT` control. You can use the [`EM_GETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to retrieve the begin and end of selected text, then use [`WM_GETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the complete text. Do not use [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because it does not work with windows of another process.
In general, you can try using the [`WM_COPY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. This should place the text in the clipboard. However, the result depends on how that message handler is implemented in the other application.

Comment: One more note: The messages must be sent to the control containing the text; this is usually a child window of the application window.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the clipboard using `SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, 0)` -- [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that if the second parameter is NULL, the window must process the WM_RENDERFORMAT and WM_RENDERALLFORMATS messages; the same article has a comment on how to allocate Global memory, fill it with the required text and pass it on to `SetClipboardData()`.